# Objective-C: AudioOutputUnitStart takes a long time to start. Possible workaround? 

Tags: objective-c, core-audio

AudioOutputUnitStart function takes up to 1-2 seconds to start every time I call it. I use AudioOutputUnitStop to stop it, is there something like AudioOutputUnitPause so that it only takes this much to start first time? Or do I have to keep it all the time started and output silence when "stopped" (this doesn't seem right)

Thanks!

EDIT: The sound I play it's pretty short (under a second, streaming continuously ) so I don't think it's that, probably that's how much it usually takes no matter the sound size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to decrease your buffer size for your audio data.
iOS will not begin playing until the first buffer is filled with data. If this buffer size is quite big, it might take 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. I made the buffer size too large. Forgot to add the answer here. However, will choose your answer because is correct.

Comment: May I ask how you changed the buffer size?

Comment: The method DeriveBufferSize() holds as third parameter a value to trim the buffer size. The resulting buffer size is changed by a pointer call in the DeriveBufferSize() method:

 DeriveBufferSize(recordState.queue, 
                  recordState.dataFormat, 
                  0.5,
                  &recordState.bufferByteSize);