# CoreAudio/OpenAL: How to get the outgoing audio signal

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, openal

I'm currently trying to get the outgoing audio signal of my iOS app to be able to send it to Audiobus. I need the AudioBufferLists which are outgoing to be able to route them. I'm using OpenAL for audio playback.

The best case would be that I can even modify the outgoing signal to put effects on it.

Comment: I found this question looking also for info on how to get an OpenAL app to output to Audiobus. Hope someone helps

Comment: Feels really good that also others try doing this and can't find an answer in the docs. I also posted the question on the Audiobus forum but no answer so far: http://heroes.audiob.us/discussion/100/openal-send-to-audiobus#Item_1
EDIT: I'm actually using CocosDenshion which is an OpenAL wrapper - if that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There currently appears to be no public API to access the output of OpenAL in an iOS app.

If you want the output, you will need to use another audio API to play the sound, such as Audio Queues with uncompressed raw PCM audio or the RemoteIO Audio Unit, in order to be able to grab the audio output buffers.

Comment: On the Audiobus forum this was suggested to me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756972/sound-capture-with-openal-on-ios  - I didn't have the time to test it yet.

Comment: ObjectAL has recording features but it says "unsupported on iOS". Is this due to OpenAL or is it just not implemented? https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALCaptureDevice.m

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out how this guy made his own audio mixing object for OpenAL so he could achieve this:

http://www.cuppadev.co.uk/openal-sucks-write-your-own-audio-mixer/

Comment: Thanks, maybe I contact the guy and ask him since it seems like he only shows his basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using OpenAL, you could use CoreAudio with the 3D Mixer Audio Unit (`kAudioUnitSubType_AU3DMixerEmbedded`).  Then you have control over where your output goes.  Obviously doing this will sacrifice some portability (you'll be OK with Mac OS X, but not Windows, Linux or Android).